# How to escape literal percent sign when NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES option is enabled?

Tags: mysql, escaping, special-characters

My company runs MySQL in NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode. How can I escape a literal `%` or `_` in a LIKE query in this mode? The standard way is `\%`, but that doesn't work in this mode.

Example: a column has the following values: `5% off`, `50% off`. The following query works in standard mode but not in NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE mycol LIKE '5\% off'
```

Comment: `%%` might do the trick?

Comment: @Marc nope, that was my first try

Answer (score 73, accepted):

you need escape

```
select * from mytable
where mycol like '5\% off' escape '\';
```

For a version that works regardless of NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode, you can use a different character, like pipe:

```
select * from mytable
where mycol like '5|% off' escape '|';
```

Comment: thanks. there need to be single-quotes around the backslash, not double-quotes.

Comment: oh, is the same since escape is being escaped in NO_BLACKSLASH_ESCAPES

Comment: @ajreal did you mean `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`?

Comment: The backslash needs to be escaped as well, I took the liberty of updating your answer.

Comment: @Benjamin actually your edit introduces a syntax error. the question is specifically asking about MySQL in NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode. In that mode, backslash is not the escape character