# mysql query not filtering AND as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the query listed below, it is out from a PDO statement. Everything in the query works fine, apart from the collectionId = 3 part. Its returning results with other intergers...

I've stared at this for a while and can't spot what is wrong, it all looks fine to me?

```
SELECT  `Hat`.`id` AS  `Hat_id` ,  `Hat`.`hatCode` AS  `Hat_hatCode` ,  `Hat`.`hatCodeOther` AS  `Hat_hatCodeOther` ,  `Hat`.`name` AS  `Hat_name` ,  `Hat`.`description` AS `Hat_description` ,  `Hat`.`colorId` AS  `Hat_colorId` ,  `Hat`.`collectionId` AS  `Hat_collectionId` ,  `Hat`.`mainPicture` AS  `Hat_mainPicture` ,  `Hat`.`subPicture` AS `Hat_subPicture` ,  `Hat`.`type` AS  `Hat_type` ,  `Hat`.`featured` AS  `Hat_featured` ,  `Hat`.`published` AS  `Hat_published` ,  `Hat`.`deleted` AS  `Hat_deleted` 
FROM  `modx_hats` AS  `Hat` 
WHERE (
`Hat`.`published` =1
AND  `Hat`.`collectionId` =  '3'
AND  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '%||2||%'
OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '2||%'
OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '%||2'
OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '2'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Check out SQL operator precendence and this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query multiple AND and OR's not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096134/sql-query-multiple-and-and-ors-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OR conditions need to be in parentheses:

```
SELECT  `Hat`.`id` AS  `Hat_id` ,  `Hat`.`hatCode` AS  `Hat_hatCode` ,  `Hat`.`hatCodeOther` AS  `Hat_hatCodeOther` ,  `Hat`.`name` AS  `Hat_name` ,  `Hat`.`description` AS `Hat_description` ,  `Hat`.`colorId` AS  `Hat_colorId` ,  `Hat`.`collectionId` AS  `Hat_collectionId` ,  `Hat`.`mainPicture` AS  `Hat_mainPicture` ,  `Hat`.`subPicture` AS `Hat_subPicture` ,  `Hat`.`type` AS  `Hat_type` ,  `Hat`.`featured` AS  `Hat_featured` ,  `Hat`.`published` AS  `Hat_published` ,  `Hat`.`deleted` AS  `Hat_deleted` 
FROM  `modx_hats` AS  `Hat` 
WHERE (
`Hat`.`published` =1
AND  `Hat`.`collectionId` =  '3'
AND  (`Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '%||2||%'
OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '2||%'
OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '%||2'
OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '2')
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: This was it - thanks, as this was the first correct answer I will accept this when I'm allowed to. Will upvote all others though :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, Added `()` for OR grouping

```
WHERE (
`Hat`.`published` =1
AND  `Hat`.`collectionId` =  '3'
AND ( `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '%||2||%'
OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '2||%'
OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '%||2'
OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '2'
)
)
```

Ref: [SQL Query multiple AND and OR's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096134/sql-query-multiple-and-and-ors-not-working/21096210#21096210)

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what exactly you would like to filter, but your problem most likely is that the conditions get evaluated differently from what you think - How do you expect the OR and AND (which have no parentheses to group them) are evaluated?

As it stands, the query returns all records which fulfill EITHER

```
`Hat`.`published` =1 AND
`Hat`.`collectionId` =  '3' AND
`Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '%||2||%' `
```

OR which fulfill any of those other restrictions:

```
OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '2||%'
OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '%||2'
OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '2'
```

It's all a matter of setting the parentheses right.
My guess is that you want all records which have published=1, collectionId=3, and one of the colorIds you give.
For this, you'd have to group it accordingly:

```
WHERE (
`Hat`.`published` =1
AND  `Hat`.`collectionId` =  '3'
AND
  (
    `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '%||2||%'
    OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '2||%'
    OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '%||2'
    OR  `Hat`.`colorId` LIKE  '2'
  )
)
```