# How do I prevent interpolation of this Ruby string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails and I have a location in my database with the name:

```
1A J@ck$on & S0n's #{10}
```

I am receiving this name via a webhook and then searching my database with it however it does not find the location name ( it is instead searching for the interpolated name:

```
1A J@ck$on & S0n's 10
```

How can I receive this string via a webhook like this:

```
@location = inbound_webhook_request['location']
```

And then put it in a pg "like" query as shown below:

```
Location.where("name ~* ?", @location['name'])
```

Without it being interpolated along the way?

Comment: That string will not be interpolated unless you are typing it into a double quoted String literal. Receiving this through a "webhook" will not cause interpolation as the `#{}` will already be escaped e.g.  `'1A J@ck$on & S0n\'s #{10}' #=> "1A J@ck$on & S0n's \#{10}"`. Your issue is that you are using pattern matching `~*` and in regex `{}` has special meaning. "{" ...when followed by a digit, it is the beginning of a bound. "{m}" a sequence of exactly m matches of the atom, so it is actually searching for `"1A J@ck$on & S0n's ##########"` (10 # in row)

Comment: Please note this is not the only special character (or character set) in regular expressions, or in your specific example. For instance `$` will match the end of a String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is not being interpolated. I'm not sure what led you to that assumption. However:

> `Location.where("name ~* ?", @location['name'])`

[This is not a LIKE operation, it's a POSIX regexp (case insensitive) operation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html).

Assuming you actually did want to perform a `LIKE` operation, not a regular expression search, you can do this:

```
Location.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{@location['name']}%")
```

or, using the shorthand syntax from the above linked documentation:

```
Location.where("name ~~ ?", "%#{@location['name']}%")
```

For a case-insensitive `LIKE`, you can use `ILIKE` or `~~*`.

If the user input needs to be further sanitised, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34949425/1954610).

Comment: Thanks very much Tom - really helpful :)