# php, mysql % searching in LIKE query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find string that have % character

For example, when one row's column has %%%%%,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%value%';
```

If value is %, it returns all.

How can I search only that row?

Comment: This link might be helpful.. [Like query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712580/list-of-special-characters-for-sql-like-clause)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape literal percent sign when NO\_BACKSLASH\_ESCAPES option is enabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020130/how-to-escape-literal-percent-sign-when-no-backslash-escapes-option-is-enabled)

Answer (score 1):

You should escape it with a backslash...

```
\%
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use any escape character with:

```
LIKE '%|%%' escape '|'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to escape all `%` characters in PHP:

```
$original_value = "%%%%%";

$temp = str_split($original_value, 1);

$escape_value = '\\'.implode('\\', $temp);

echo $escape_value;
```

Result (escaped value):

```
\%\%\%\%\%
```

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say you want to find any fields that contain the text “100%”, so you put together this query:

Square Bracket Escape:

You can surround the % or _ with square brackets to tell SQL Server that the character inside is a regular character.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE ‘%100[%]%’
```

T-SQL ESCAPE Syntax:

Alternatively, you can append the ESCAPE operator onto your query, and add a \ character before the value you want to escape.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE ‘%100\%%’ ESCAPE ‘\’
```

The ESCAPE ‘\’ part of the query tells the SQL engine to interpret the character after the \ as a literal character instead of as a wildcard.

The easiest way is to include the characters I don't want, for example square brackets and slash:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Name LIKE '%[\]\[/]%' ESCAPE '\'
```