# mysql like string which contains %

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I created a database for newsletter and i save campaigns. Also i add campaign code in customer table. for example i have a campagin with code "collagen" ana code "solgar-51%" and i save it in emailcampaign column "collagen, solgar-51%". Some customer have both of them. I want `emailcampaign` column like end of "solgar-51%".

This work

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `customer` 
WHERE  `emailcampaign` LIKE  '%solgar -51%%'
```

but this NOT

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `customer` 
WHERE  `emailcampaign` LIKE  'solgar -51%%'
```

neither this

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `customer` 
WHERE  `emailcampaign` LIKE  'solgar -51%%'
```

Comment: `.. like '%solgar -51\%' escape '\'`

Comment: like '%solgar -51\%' is string starts with it and like '%/solgar -51%' is string ends with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try \%:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `customer` 
WHERE  `emailcampaign` LIKE  '%solgar -51\%'
```

Comment: but if '%solgar -51%' are twice in emailcampaign (2nd campaign with same name from user) this is not correct

Comment: Use something like this `str_replace('%', '\%', $user_value);` if you want to remove percents from string

Comment: But it is more better to use PDO and parameters

Answer (score 0):

Escape '\'

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `customer` 
WHERE  `emailcampaign` LIKE  '%solgar -51\%' escape '\';
```

More [detailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020130/how-to-escape-literal-percent-sign-when-no-backslash-escapes-option-is-enabled)