# How to escape the % and \ signs in pymysql using LIKE clause?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I want to find something like "probability: 10%" or "10% high" in my 'events' column, but when I used the code below:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user='myid', passwd='mypwd', db='mydb', charset='utf8')
curs = conn.cursor()

key = "%"
curs.execute(
        "SELECT count(*) AS number FROM city WHERE events LIKE %s",
        ("%" + key + "%",)
    )
```

it returned every row in the table. It executed this query:

```
  SELECT count(*) AS number FROM city WHERE events LIKE '%%%'
```

like this, which I didn't intend.

Searching for the backslash sign also gave me incorrect results.

What should I do to get the correct result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MySQL uses C-style escaping so to get a backslash in a string (before it gets sent to `LIKE`) you need two backslashes. Try `SELECT count(*) AS number FROM city WHERE events LIKE '%\\%%'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020130/how-to-escape-literal-percent-sign-when-no-backslash-escapes-option-is-enabled

Comment: So do I need to define a new function to escape that wildcard chracters? I heard that pymysql execute function escape the string, but it doesn't?

Comment: it does, but like with `%` is a special case. pymysql can't see the difference between the `%` signs in '`%s%s%s'` which is what you're passing in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

instead of the concat the wildchar in param you could use concat in SQL  and pass the value

```
 curs.execute(
    "SELECT count(*) AS number FROM city WHERE events LIKE CONCAT('%', %s, '%')",
     (key ,)
)
```

or as uggested  by @Notinlist

curs.execute(
"SELECT count(*) AS number FROM city WHERE events LIKE CONCAT('%%', %s, '%%')",
(key ,)
)

Comment: It gave an error to me `unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index ...`. The solution was to use `"SELECT ... LIKE CONCAT('%%', %s, '%%')"`

Comment: @Notinlist  .. thanks  ..answer  updated  with your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You ought to use SQL ESCAPE clause:

```
curs.execute(
    "SELECT count(*) AS number FROM city WHERE events LIKE '%#%%' ESCAPE '#'"
)
```

Comment: so there is no function in pymysql that helps escaping the word like '\' or '%'?
I thought when using string to second parameter of excute function, pymysql automatically escape string. it doesn't?