# SQL Backslash in Like Statement - Proper Use

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to inquire if it is important to treat the backslashes in a SQL statement in order to get the correct counts? This is an example:

```
Select users from table1 where screenname like '/welcome?optin=%'
```

Do I need to inject additional treatment to the special characters in the like statement to ensure correct counts? I do not get an error running this query but I wonder if it is returning more counts than it should.

Comment: The only chars that need additional treatment (escaping) when you use LIKE would be `%` and `_`. Slash and backslash are not special chars: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: Ah, does it mean in my statement needs treatment due to the "%" character only?

Comment: No, the only case that % and _ need escaping is if you want to match these chars. If you want them to behave like wildcards then you don't have to do anything.

Comment: In my case, the characters in the string represent the exact string and not wildcards. In this case then, I need treatment due to the existing %, yes?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020130/how-to-escape-literal-percent-sign-when-no-backslash-escapes-option-is-enabled/5020292) will show you how to escape that.

Comment: If this is the case then yes, but why then you don't use `=` instead of LIKE?