# MySql LIKE operator escape multiple percentage (%) character

Tags: mysql

```
select * from Table
where name like '%\%\%\%\%%'
```

the above code snipped was supposed to fetch rows that contains 4 percentage sign. But instead it fetch rows that contains at least one percentage sing .

How can i achieve the goal of the code (find rows that contains at least 4 percentage sign)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape literal percent sign when NO\_BACKSLASH\_ESCAPES option is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020130/how-to-escape-literal-percent-sign-when-no-backslash-escapes-option-is-enabled)

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. If you run the query mentioned in the post, you can see the unusual behaviour.